# How do I synchronise bookmarks from Firefox with Ubuntu One automatically?

Tags: ubuntu-one, firefox, bookmarks

I don't know if this is possible and already done automatically when logging in with Ubuntu One, but can I synchronise bookmarks from Firefox to Ubuntu One automatically?

So that I can add bookmarks on the same computer from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.10 or even from a newer installation of Ubuntu.

If it is possible, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

We did have a bookmark synchronisation solution for Ubuntu One in the shape of the [Bindwood](https://launchpad.net/bindwood) extension.  As that depended on CouchDB synchronisation, which [we have since disabled](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-November/003474.html), it is no longer a viable option.

It may get resurrected when [U1DB](https://launchpad.net/u1db) matures, but for now we do not have a good synchronisation solution that will merge changes between sets of bookmarks in a useful way.

For now, you might want to try out Firefox's built in bookmark synchronisation, which can be configured from the `Sync` tab of its preferences window.

Comment: http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2011/10/17/putting-bookmark-sync-to-bed/ is a post more explicitly related to bookmark sync. The CouchDB announcement you linked was not to say we have disabled sync, but that we will be doing so. CouchDB is not yet entirely disabled, but I'd advise against new users using any features dependent on it. Bookmarks sync however, is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, this should work for you:

Go to `~/.mozilla`, or`/home/your-user-name/.mozilla`. Inside the .mozilla folder you will notice a **firefox** folder. Look inside the **firefox** folder for your user profile folder, it will have a series of numbers and letters (something like this: `u7qqadwy.default`). Inside that folder you'll see a folder called `bookmarkbackups`. Open the backup's folder and you'll notice a few different files which will be named with a date and a json extension on the end like this: `bookmarks-2012-04-13.json`. Simply copy the latest few dated files to your new profile and place them in the same firefox directory. You'll need to open Firefox and go to Bookmarks-Show All Bookmarks. From there click on the import & backup link. You'll get a pop-up window that should open in the same directory you pasted the old bookmarks into. Select the latest one and choose import. You'll now have your old bookmarks in the new profile.

You can do the same thing if you have saved passwords. Just go to the `.mozilla` folder open your profile folder again and copy the `cert8.db`, `permissions.sqlite`, and `signons.sqlite` files. Paste those files into the new directory over-writing the old ones and restart Firefox.